# Is it required to restart JBOSS after updating the module.xml?

Tags: jboss

I am a Siemens Teamcenter Implementation consultant and have limited knowledge of JBOSS.
I have a question-related to JBOSS module dependencies.
Before asking a question, I will quickly give the background.

**Background**

JBoss version is EAP 6.1.0 installed in Linux.
For one of the POC in the Teamcenter application, we need to deploy the EAR file in JBOSS.
The company provided the shared JBOSS where other applications from the different departments also using the JBOSS.
JBOSS is used in domain mode.

**Problem**

For deploying the EAR file for Teamcenter application, I need to update the module.xml with JMX dependency. Since the JBOSS is shared by many applications of different departments, we need to get permission from each of them to restart the JBOSS. ( This restart point I want to confirm)

**Question**

Is it required to restart the JBOSS for module.xml update?

or

Is there another way to add the dependency in classpath without restarting the JBOSS.

Comment: Why do you need to change the module.xml? And which  module.xml are you changing?

Comment: Hi Simon, Thank you for your comment. I need to change module.xml for allowing JBoss connector module to use JMX MBeans. ( As specificed in Teamcenter documentation). For that I need to add org.jboss.as.jmx module as dependency in module.xml of connector module

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the `module.xml` of a module that's been loaded you'll need to restart the server.